# "If you are not [a] vegan" - should there be an article?

Tags: articles

I'm not sure about the sentence in the title.

I feel like there should be an article, but I often see how people write **"I'm vegan"** omitting the article.

Why do they omit it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88599/discussion-on-question-by-john-dean-if-you-are-not-a-vegan-should-there-be).

Answer (score 1):

Because the term *vegan* can be a noun or an adjective, it would be correct English either to use the article *or* not use it.

Having said that, the distinction between the two only becomes apparent when the term is then applied to a person in a **negative** context. It’s a very subtle discrimination initially, but it opens the door to bigotry along the lines of ‘Jewish’ and ‘a Jew’, or ‘black’ and ‘a black’.

Try to see it as the difference between describing a person as *alien* (adjective) or as *an alien* (noun).

If I use an *adjective* to describe a person, then the noun *person* is implied by the pronoun *he/she*.

> e.g. She is ugly. *meaning*: That is an ugly *person*.

Despite the **negative** meaning of the adjective, the assumption remains that we are still talking about *a person*.

But if I use *alien* as an adjective, then I can only use it to describe something that is ‘alien’ *about* a person - their mannerisms, their appearance, language, etc. - otherwise there is confusion as to whether I still consider them to be *a person*.

Because *an alien* cannot also be *a person*. If I refer to someone as *an alien*, particularly in a **negative** context, then I call into question their personhood, their humanity - even as I continue to use the pronouns *he/she*. The noun *alien* effectively **replaces** the noun *person* in how one makes sense of who they are. It effectively challenges the assumption that we’re talking about *a person*, thereby giving permission to see them as ‘not a person’.

So every time we *describe* a person using a noun, we challenge the assumption that we are still talking about *a person*. Then when the context becomes **negative**, we give permission to others to treat the one labelled in this way as ‘not a person’.

Comment: Negativity from a noun term is a possibility, but it's the uncommon exception to the normal rule. In the majority of situations, this doesn't apply. (*I'm a democrat.* *I'm a Christian*. *I'm a doctor.* Nobody would say that any of those denotes nonpersons.)

Comment: @JasonBassford, are you suggesting that nobody would treat a democrat with less dignity than a human deserves, with hatred, fear or vilification, simply because he’s seen as ‘a democrat’? That nobody who follows another faith or even militant atheism would *dismiss* or even *hate* another person who is referred to as ‘a Christian’? It is the identification as ‘other’ that makes it so easy to think - *I’m a person, but you’re a democrat*.

Comment: I'm not saying it's *impossible*, I'm just saying it's highly unlikely. You're making far bigger deal out of something that's normally irrelevant than you have to. You seem to be saying that nobody should be referred to by any noun other than *person*. (Almost as if you're advocating dispensing with other nouns.)  But, by the same token, that also means that referring to somebody as a *person* takes away from every *other* noun you could refer to them as. Surely other nouns have just as much legitimacy.

Comment: Wow! Now I'm even more confused.

Can you please examine this full sentence: **If you are not [a] vegan, you can choose this option.** Should there be an article? If not, why?

Comment: I did say it is correct with or without the article, and I stand by it for this new sentence. Jason is right that I’m making a bigger deal out of this than is needed. I was offering a reason why people tend to omit the article (it’s part of the question). When in the minority, have you noticed that we choose the adjective rather than the noun - explaining *’I’m Christian’* if staying with a Jewish family during Ramadan, or *’I voted democrat’* when surrounded by passionate republicans? I’d call it self-protection, in a sense. But feel free to ignore it like everyone else...